# Нужно создать таблицу города и станции метро, как лучше всего это сделать?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Нужно ли создать отдельную таблицу для городов или совместить города и станции метро в одной таблице ?

Как понять когда нужна отдельная таблица ?

Если есть ссылки на эту тему буду рад посмотреть.

Comment: А еще есть линии.
А еще может появиться желание хранить другие объекты и их координаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При продумывании архитектуры БД, необходимо руководствоваться рядом условий.

Например, если есть таблица `cities` и `stations` нужно задаться вопросом отношений этих таблиц.
Может ли один город иметь несколько связанных записей в таблице `stations` ? Конечно может, тогда вопрос обратный, может ли иметь одна станция несколько связанных записей в таблице `cities`? Однозначно нет. Значит связь между таблицами - `hasOne(один ко многим)`. Значит достаточно в таблице `stations` добавить колонку `city_id`. И отдельная таблица не нужна.

А теперь представим, что у нас таблица `station_names` содержит только имена станций. В таком случае, у нас может быть ситуация, что одно и то же имя может встречаться у нескольких городов. Тогда отношение будет `manyToMany(многие ко многим)`. Вот в этом случае нужна отдельная таблица, содержащая как минимум 2 колонки `city_id` и `station_name_id`

Так же есть такой приём как денормализация БД, это когда специально нарушаются [нормальные формы БД](https://office-menu.ru/uroki-sql/51-normalizatsiya-bazy-dannykh) для удобства хранения данных. Всё зависит от конкретных условий и сложности архитектуры БД.

Comment: Ну про нормализацию таблиц я знаю, 
данные поступают из таблицы и их больше   миллиона не хочется создавать отдельную таблицу  так как данные   изменятся не будут,
 хотел узнать есть ли случаи когда  можно обойти без нормализации таблиц ?